# Class variables and instance variables - which one to use and why, common patterns

Tags: python, oop, variables

There is one thing that I have in back of my head when using some common libraries (like scrapy/django etc...). I know some top level difference between:

1. Class variables - shared among all classes, `my_class_var` not in class.__dict__, defined like:

```py
class SomeClass:
    my_class_var = 1
```

2. Class variables - every instance have it's own, `my_instance_var` in class.__dict__, defined like:

```py
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_instance_var = 1
```

But when i use for instance scrapy, documentation says to use class variables:

```py
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class CustomItem(Item):
    one_field = Field()
```

Exactly the same can be seen in Django for ORM representations. So this is what I wonder about:

1. Why to use it in this way? Usually when we create some `Item` in scrapy, there are many instance of this class and all differs. So why to use Class Variables?
2. Is there any adventage of using Class Variables? What is it?
3. Would it be impossible/not advised to declare it as Instance Variables?

Thank in advance for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: In the scrapy example `one_field` presumably is a class variable, because it is an attribute of the `CustomItem` class which is shared by all instances. Each instance has its own *value* for the field, but the *field* is the same for all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class variables in such cases, e.g. ORM, are not used to store data but as a description or template. Variables with these names are also created in each instance of the class (in the hidden `__init__` method), in this case they are used to store data. This is a little magic that ORM hides from the user.

Comment: Yea, i was doing little reserach yesterday, and it seems to be the same for other package - like scrapy. Behind the scenes, Super Class is taking info from this Class Variables, and they create more 'secure' variables.

Answer (score -1):

The difference between instance and class variable is that when you have an instance variable, it is specific to that instance, class variable is the same for all the instances in class. To access class variable, you don't even need to have any instance instantiated. See the following example:

```
class Foo():
    class_variable = 0

    def __init__(self):
        Foo.class_variable += 1
        self.variable = Foo.class_variable


print(Foo.class_variable)
instance1 = Foo()
print(Foo.class_variable)
print(instance1.variable)
instance2 = Foo()
print(Foo.class_variable)
print(instance1.variable)
print(instance2.variable)
```

Which should return this:

```
0
1
1
2
1
2
```